# require_once(PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php) in yii

Tags: phpunit, composer-php, yii-components

i'm trying to use phpunit in yii

i followed the instruction to install it from http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/installation.html

when i'm doing this

```
phpunit protected/tests/unit/
```

this error happend

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/news/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php on line 12
```

when i'm trying to install SeleniumTestCase again throw

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2"
```

this is what appeared

```
Changed current directory to /home/qts1234/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev) 
Nothing to install or update 
Generating autoload files
```

what can i do . please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the selenium scripts globally with composer does not add them to your include path nor will it be seen by the autoloader.

You should instead add `phpunit/phpunit-selenium` as a development dependency and have composer install it into your project so your bootstrap can load the autoloader and the tests you are extending will be found.

Comment: I did as said, installed it and the other dependencies(Invoker, DBunit etc ) through composer and the files are on vendor folder as expected, but I keep getting this exactly error. Any other suggestion? I'm in yii 1.1.

Comment: @Shad are you including the autoloader in your phpunit bootstrap script?

Comment: http://saa.dfarooq.com/blog/2014/01/10/phpunit-with-yii-and-composer/ lists some of the missing components.